# Consume Spring Boot REST service in JBOSS Seam Application

Tags: rest, spring-boot, seam2

I was interested to know if a Spring Boot REST service can be consumed in a JBOSS Seam Application. If yes, what would be the steps.
Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can consume Spring Boot REST service or any RESTful endpoints. 
Just like any other Java application, you would need the implementations of using RestTemplate and binding, convert(parse)ing, and Header.  And FYI, you can still use Spring with JBOSS Seam.